# JQuery Form Styling Plugins?

Tags: jquery, css

Anyone know any good (good design) JQuery form styling plugin?  I can't seem to find some with decent styling design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out:

- [15 jQuery Plugins to enhance your HTML form elements](http://www.dreamcss.com/2009/05/15-jquery-plugins-to-enhance-your-html.html)

Answer (score 0):

To style my forms I would go for a solution like [Wufoo](http://wufoo.com).
Styling is better if it's just css related in my opinion.
I wouldn't feel comfortable with a bunch of JQuery plugins that are messing around with my layout.
I would suggest to give Wufoo a try.